# Getting broken link error whle Using App Engine service accounts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm following this tutorial

```
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-appengine
```

Here is my main.py code

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

# BigQuery API Settings
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXX' # REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID

# Create a new API service for interacting with BigQuery
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
bigquery_service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)


class ListDatasets(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    datasets = bigquery_service.datasets()
    listReply = datasets.list(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER).execute()
    self.response.out.write('Dataset list:')
    self.response.out.write(listReply)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/listdatasets(.*)', ListDatasets)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here is my app.yaml file code

```
application: bigquerymashup
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

And yes i have added app engine service account name in google api console Team tab with can edit permissions.
When upload the app and try to access the link it says

```
Oops! This link appears to be broken.
```

Ealier i ran this locally and tried to access it using link `localhost:8080`.Then i thought may be running locally might be giving the error so i uploaded my code to

```
http://bigquerymashup.appspot.com/
```

but still its giving error.

**EDIT:**
Updated App.yaml

```
application: bigquerymashup
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /listdatasets
  script: main.py
```

But getting another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp2‌​5.py", line 710, in call handler.get(*groups) TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: 1. Did you add your Project Number on this line?

    PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXX' # REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID

2. What link are you trying to reach? What does your app.yaml file look like?

Comment: ys i did add Project Number.I have updated the question with app.yaml and rest of the details.I tried to reach using localhost:8080 and http://bigquerymashup.appspot.com/ where i uploaded the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a Script Handlers that matches the URL you are trying to locate.

Try: `http://[your_app_id_here].appspot.com/listdatasets`

Read more about handlers [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Script_Handlers).

Comment: i just updated my app.yaml(updated app.yaml in question too) as u said and tried browsing the link http://bigquerymashup.appspot.com/listdatasets but now its giving another error                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 710, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Change "/listdatasets(.*)" to "/listdatasets". Note also your updated app.yaml is incorrect - you don't need to the have the "url: /listdatasets" line in your app.yaml. The catchall "url: .*" handler should go last anyway, as it will match every URL before hitting the /listdatasets handler below it. This is beyond the scope of your original question (and is all explained in the link above) but I'll take a look at updating our sample.

Comment: thnks dat worked fine.I just have one more doubt.In order for this thing to work i had to upload it to appspot.Is dere any way to run this in localhost using App Engine Service Accounts

Comment: No, currently there is no way to use  App Engine Service Accounts locally.